# Reading File in Python 3

Tags: python

I have below data in one of the file:

```
{'name': 'A', 'age': 30}
{'name': 'B', 'age': 31}
{'name': 'C', 'age': 32}
{'name': 'D', 'age': 33}
{'name': 'E', 'age': 34}
```

If I have only one pair of value `{'name': A, 'age': 30}` then I can get the key value pair by doing `a = {'name': A, 'age': 30} print(a['name'])`. But once I have multiple key value pair then how to read the data?

Comment: It's not clear to me if your problem is how to read anything from a file or how to write a loop.

Comment: share the code please.

Comment: You read AND parse line by line. That's it.

Comment: You could put them in a list and then do `for a in data_list: print(a['name'])`. Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: Are you asking how to handle it if there is a second object with a duplicate name?

Comment: Hello @tdelaney,
Thank for the help and this is what I needed. I have one last issue with me. Example if I have one more data entry {'name': 'A', 'age': 30, 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800))}

Comment: Hello @tdelaney,
When I execute the code-
with open(jsonFilePathNFO) as data_file:
    convData = [ast.literal_eval(data) for data in data_file]

for data in convData:
    print(data)

I get below error:-

ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Call object at 0x0000023586533DF0>

Comment: Thanks All for helping me. I ll take care of putting more information while asking any help.

Comment: You say you have a file but then your demonstration is `a = {'name': A, 'age': 30}`, suggesting that in fact you have a python script. In your comment it looks llike you really do have a file, so the question is, how was that file written? What was the format of that file. It looks like each line is the python literal for a dictionary, so the answer below seems reasonable. But is it?

Comment: Hello @tdelaney,
First of all I am very new to python world. So please forgive me if I sound unmatured. And you are right I do have a file and that comes from the API call. My code to store the API call value is:-
Variable = API_Call (So when I see the variable property then it shows that the variable type is a list).
Later I read the variable and store the file in Json or text file.
Also the API description says that the file format is Json. But when I use Json commands then I get some error.

Comment: Hello @tdelaney,
Any help :(

Answer (score 1):

use `ast` - the output is list of dictionaries. Each dict represent a line.

```
import ast 
with open('data.txt') as f:
  data = [ast.literal_eval(l) for l in f]
print(data)
```

data.txt

```
{'name': 'A', 'age': 30}
{'name': 'B', 'age': 31}
{'name': 'C', 'age': 32}
{'name': 'D', 'age': 33}
{'name': 'E', 'age': 34}
```

output

```
[{'name': 'A', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'B', 'age': 31}, {'name': 'C', 'age': 32}, {'name': 'D', 'age': 33}, {'name': 'E', 'age': 34}]
```